# Connect to JDBC DataSource Using JNDI Websphere

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere, datasource, jndi

I am trying to connect to a datasource available in my websphere 7.0 server through eclipse.

Below is the code.

```
Hashtable<String, String> pdEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        pdEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");             
        pdEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://XX.XXX.XX.XX:YYYY");

        Connection connection =null;



        Context initialContext = new InitialContext(pdEnv);
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/AEDS");

        if (datasource != null) {
          connection = datasource.getConnection("admin","admin"); // DB credintials
        } else {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
```

But i am getting the below exception while trying to connect to it

```
Exception in thread "P=365798:O=0:CT" javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: A communication failure occurred while attempting to obtain an initial context with the provider URL: 
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mapInitialReferenceFailure(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:2271)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getWsnNameService(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1457)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:987)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:581)
```

I am also confused about the port number to be used with iiop url as we have multiple server running on the same node and each having different bootstrap port.

Comment: At what scope have you configured the DataSource?

Comment: Scope for datasource is cell

Comment: The port you use should be the one for which server you usually access the data source, but as you are using the Cell it should not matter. You also need to check the host name. If you on the same client machine just try to connect to the port, does something answer on that port or do you get connection refused? (you could try telnet to that host name and port)

Comment: I have used the same bootstrap server port ,but i am getting Unknown host exeption .tried to ping the host and it was sucessfull

Comment: If you are getting Unknown host, that is really where you should start. If you try the IP-address, will it work?

Comment: Also, I saw another note on that matter and in that case, no matter how the service was connected, the host name was transferred back through the connection, but it was not fully qualified, so they had to "Adding "springfield.net" to my DNS search suffixes, resolved the error", last comment of this thread: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013947242

Comment: A question: Why are you trying to access the datasource through iiop? Could you explain us what are you trying to do and what is your Wesbsphere setup? In case you just want to get a connection from a datasource you do not need the pdEnv variable.